# phpstorm 404 (Not Found)

Tags: http-status-code-404

I have a problem with bellow code. At first I wrote it in Phpstorm and it worked correctly, but when I used wamp64 and copy the folders in Wamp's project folder the **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)** accrued. I select the directory as Resourse roots from **SETTING>DIRECTORY**, but it doesn't work yet. This is my code.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDACs.png)
[settind>directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoaYg.png)

Comment: please post your code as text, not an image - images of text are not very helpful because we cant copy/paste to try it out. thanks!

Comment: <script src="/assets/js/jquery3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.min.css/style.css" >

    <script src="/assets/js/script.js" ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/fonticon.css">